# Domain validated Certificate - SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate - BoringSSL problems

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I just recognized that my app does not get a SSL Connection to my server for devices running android 5 or lower. Here comes the error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

I tested my app during development on Android 6 and all worked properly.

My domain contains the SSL-Certificate, so I did not need to put it on the server. Do you know how to get a SSL-Connection for devices which are not running Android 6?

In Android 6 there is a change from OpenSSL to BoringSSL :
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html
Could inserting BoringSSL Libraries into the app be a solution? And does anyone know how it works?
Thanks very much

Comment: check the server with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for any problems. Or just add the URL of your server to the question.  And "My domain contains the SSL-Certificate, so I did not need to put it on the server." makes not really sense: the server needs to provide the certificate to the client.

Comment: I already checked the Server, but there are no errors at SSLLabs.
I bought an One-Click SSL-Certificate at strato.de.
__
Leider gibt es keine Möglichkeit Privatnachrichten zu schreiben, dann könnte ich Ihnen die Domain zukommen lassen. MfG